# White Screen of Death

Tags: macos, mac, mac-pro, startup

[image]

As seen in the picture above, my Mac Pro is getting the white screen of death. Immediately after turning on, it goes to this - no startup chime, no Apple logo, nothing. I have tried:
- Resetting SMC
- Resetting PRAM
- Holding shift on startup
- Trying to boot into recovery mode (Cmd+R)
But none of these change anything, the white screen stays.

Comment: Can you give us more information? Which model Mac Pro? What OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule 1 of troubleshooting, "Isolate and identify."

Remove anything you can to still have a bootable computer. That includes RAM, PCI cards, drives, memory risers. Then swap out the memory with the RAM you removed. Unplug **everything,** even your keyboard and mouse, leave only the monitor connected. And if you have another monitor you can use temporarily...

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks, this worked. I had a backup drive connected and it had failed in some way. Thanks for your help!